# Math.Sign with Object parameter

Tags: .net

What is the best (fastest) way to determine a sign of a numeric value passed in as Object? Just to make it clear, the value might be an int, double, Decimal or anything else comparable to 0. So we need Math.Sign analogue with object parameter in.

The solution needs to take into account boxing/unboxing concerns as well.

Comment: This is an XY question.  X is "how to avoid boxing".  That should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The solution needs to take into account boxing/unboxing concerns as well.

What does this mean? Since you get an `Object` anyway, unboxing always happens.

The simplest solution is to convert the object to `double` and get the sign:

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(obj);
return Math.Sign(d);
```

However, I would seriously question the design of your software if there are situations where an arbitrary number type gets boxed and passed to a function. This shouldn’t normally happen.

Comment: That is the question? is Convert.ToDouble the fastest way to do it? Why not Convert.ToInt(obj)? I am looking for fastest Sign(object) implementation. Thanks

Comment: @husayt I’d say so. If the type is completely unconstrained then there aren’t too many possibilities anyway. Marc’s `dynamic` variant will involve at least an additional method lookup for the `<` operator at runtime.

Comment: @husayt run ToInt32 through `decimal.MaxValue` ;p

Comment: @Konrad So that means, ToDouble is faster than dynamic?

Comment: @Mark Yes, was wrong example. Just was wondering why Konrad was prefering ToDouble to any other method?

Comment: @husayt Exactly for the reason Marc mentioned: `double` has the largest fidelity of all types. For example, converting a very small double value (`double.Epsilon`) to `int` or `float` would result in a wrong sign as well. No other type except `double` reliably reproduces the sign of all numbers of a given type.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
bool isNeg = ((dynamic)value) < 0;
```

?

I haven't tested it for all types, but looks feasible.

Update: seems to work for most:

```
static void Main()
{
    ShowNeg(byte.MinValue); ShowNeg(byte.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(ushort.MinValue); ShowNeg(ushort.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(uint.MinValue); ShowNeg(uint.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(ulong.MinValue); ShowNeg(ulong.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(sbyte.MinValue); ShowNeg(sbyte.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(short.MinValue); ShowNeg(short.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(int.MinValue); ShowNeg(int.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(long.MinValue); ShowNeg(long.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(float.MinValue); ShowNeg(float.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(double.MinValue); ShowNeg(double.MaxValue);
    ShowNeg(decimal.MinValue); ShowNeg(decimal.MaxValue);
}
static void ShowNeg(object value)
{
    bool isNeg = ((dynamic)value) < 0;
    Console.WriteLine(isNeg);
}
```

Comment: @husayt because `dynamic` caches the implementation per type, it should be pretty good. The only real way to answer that, though, is to profile

Comment: When I ran this through a simple StopWatch test (with testing every type, using your and Konrad's implementations of `ShowNeg`), the version using dynamic was slower.  However, this is the kind of test that I would prefer running against the real-world data.  My test is too focused and makes assumptions (e.g., types are equally likely).  That said, if this function is legitimately being called in a tight loop on objects, then I would suggest fixing the loop to avoid needing `Math.Sign` to take an `Object` would provide far greater benefits.

Answer (score 0):

> or anything else comparable to 0

Then cast it to IComparable.